# How to find out what Sender Profile/Send Classification was used for a send

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, reporting, send-email, deliverability

The email tracking reports show you which data extensions, suppression lists, subscription lists etc were used to send an email, but I can see nowhere on the report that tells you what sender profile/classification was used to send the email. Is there a way to find this out?

Answer (score 4):

Through a Query Activity you will be able to extract the Send Classification and the Send Definition for any specific job, by looking into the Data View: Job
http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_job/

Comment: Thanks - what should the target data extension look like for this? What columns should it have?